# Penrose Tile generator

Tags: geometry, math-software, tiling

Does anyone know if there's a client or web app that generates Penrose patterns which can then be converted to a tileable rectangular background image for web site?

I found this http://stephencollins.net/penrose but I can't seem to get a rectangular shape out of it for web use. Thanks.

Comment: Just crop it !!

Comment: This question is one of those questions that can provoke true insight in a subject :) (when answered properly and with some effort of the questioner to really try to understand what they were asking)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe, since Penrose tilings are aperiodic (lacking translational symmetry), there isn't such a rectangular shape.

Comment: That's too bad. But I can see why it's not feasible.

Comment: @Jin Then again, various lobbies and rooms across the world have been tiled with Penrose tiles.  Some of these places are probably rectangular or roughly so.  Also the kite and dart Penrose pattern uses rhombuses, and thus are angled such that a rectangular space could be filled (if the rules allow).

Comment: Being able to fill a rectangular region is different from creating a *tileable* rectangle (a rectangle for which opposite edges can be glued together to continue the pattern seamlessly).

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://logn.net/penrose/download/) java software that exports as PNG. 
You cannot tile it, just use an image.

Answer (score 1):

Only dragging up an old post because there's still something more to do -- if you want a penrose tiling as a background, I built one a while ago that will generate an image for your purpose:

https://github.com/etisab/penrosetiler

Of course the tiles don't fit perfectly into a rectangle (they are clipped at the edges), it should work just fine as a pretty background image.

Answer (score 0):

here is a shadertoy program for 5 axis quasi symmetry pics, it's not as tileable as a tile version.

I just wrote a program to investigate 5 fold symmetry in 2d, it generates something akin to penrose tiling.
here is a pic 
[image]
[and a video on YT:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llAZi7aXDt4)

i am not convinced that it can't practically be tiled in a square shape, you may have places where only one triangle is wrong in a frame of 1000 of them or something, else you could find a place with good 4 fold symmetry and blur some small places where is different on the edge.

Answer (score 0):

I found this page, it generates an SVG image: https://craftdesignonline.com/penrose/